# NativeScript IOS retrive Image URL from PHAsset objects

Tags: ios, nativescript

How can I get/build image URL from PHAsset objects? I want to get the full path so that I can show the image in view or upload it in remote server. I tried like this:

```
let data = NSMutableArray.arrayWithArray(assets);
let val = data.objectAtIndex(0);
```

I am getting the value like this:

```
burstIdentifier: null
    burstSelectionTypes: 0
    creationDate: Thu Aug 09 2012 02:52:11 GMT+0800 (CST)
    duration: 0
    favorite: false
    hidden: false
    mediaSubtypes: 0
    mediaType: 1
    pixelHeight: 2002
    pixelWidth: 3000
    representsBurst: false
    sourceType: 1
    localIdentifier: 9F983DBA-EC35-42B8-8773-B597CF782EDD/L0/001
```

But how can I build complete URL? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am getting it like this: "<PHAsset: 0x7faeeee97150> ED7AC36B-A150-4C38-BB8C-B6D696F4F2ED/L0/001 mediaType=1/0, sourceType=1, (3000x2002), creationDate=2012-08-08 21:55:30 +0000, location=1, hidden=0, favorite=0"
How did you solve this problem?

Comment: @Stefan, you can have a look here: https://github.com/jibon57/nativescript-mediafilepicker/blob/3d739936404be1246965d1374a18f4a7eb530844/src/mediafilepicker.ios.ts#L118